# How can I reduce my Class Name in Zend to call it from any where in application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, naming-conventions

I want to follow [Zend file naming convention](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html).

I have **Object.php** file with a class and a function in it.

**MyZendProject->application->models->Test->Object.php**

```
class Model_Test_Object {     
   public function test() {
    echo "Test"; 
   }
}
```

Now I want to access above test function in following file but it is not finding it.

**MyZendProject->application->modules->test->controllers->TestController.php**

```
$testModel = new Model_Test_Object();
$testModel->test();
```

But when I name the class `Application_Model_Test_Object` in **Object.php** and call it in TestController like this then it works.

```
$testModel = new Application_Model_Test_Object();
$testModel->test();
```

Problem is that I don't want to use **Application** in class name because it is too long and ugly. Is there any way that I name the class `Model_Test_Object` and access it anywhere in application without including any file. I have seen somewhere in **Botstrap.php** to solve this issue but I did not remember it and unable to find it again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you've an autoloader running? Which? Please show how you configure it.

Comment: @rik: I am configuring it first time. Can you tell me that where will I find autoloader configuration to show you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write Your own autoloader
in bootstrap:

```
  protected function _initAutoload()
  {
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); 
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('My_'); 
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  =>  APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' =>  '',
        'resourceTypes' =>  array(
            'form'  =>  array(
                'path'  =>  'forms/',
                'namespace' =>  'Form_'
            ),
            'model' =>  array(
                'path'  =>  'models/',
                'namespace' =>  'Model_'
            )
        )
    ));
    return $autoLoader;
  }
```

This will also register namespace My_ for Your own libraries

Comment: Thanks Adam. It is working now with `Model_Test_Object` name. But I did not understand the purpose of **My_**. Where can I use this?

Comment: In library directory You have Zend subdir and Zend_CLASS-NAME directories in it, there are all Zend classes. You can create Your own plugins, components etc. in Your directory. This script creates namespace My_ so You can create library/My/Plugin/Plugin.php and access it by $foo = new My_Plugin_Plugin().

This is helpful with for example Acl plugins or other custom functionality that You want to have in every ZF project.

Comment: Ok. It is working for default module. But models and forms for other modules are not accessible in even in their own module's controllers. Can you provide some more detail to do this in other modules as well. I have a question for this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891403/unable-to-access-module-forms-in-module-controller

Answer (score 1):

that is the way it will work with me

```
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

then when u just include the file

```
./
/application
 /models
   /x.php
 ...
```

just include"x.php" and it will work

Comment: Where will I place your above code. And I want to place my **Object.php** file in `zendproject/application/models/Test/`.

Comment: Your solution is little inflexible and in my opinion not follow ZF coding standards

Comment: @Awan in the public/index.php
@Adam this is the way ZF user to include file in the class lib !!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line into your configs/application.ini

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Models"

Answer (score 1):

I also don't like the very long model names in ZF i.e. class Application_Model_DbTable_SomeTableName

Retaining Pear-style naming conventions and auto discovery... this is how I solved it:

1: add the following to your index.php include_path:
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.'../models') //depends on where your index.php file is located.

2: add this line to your application.ini
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Model_"

3: create a folder inside your models folder and name is Model

4: name your model class like this Model_SomeTableName and save all your model classes in the new models/Model folder.

now in your controller you can simply call $m = new Model_SomeTableName(); and it will be automatically found and included.