# Unable to connect to MySQL in Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to connect mysql table(Authentication) in zend application using [this tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html). But unable to get instance of DbTable. I only changed the [directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483151/how-can-i-reduce-my-class-name-in-zend-to-call-it-from-any-where-in-application) in my application.

I have **Mapper** something like this:

```
class Model_Authentication_Mapper {

    protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable( $dbTable ) {

        if (is_string( $dbTable ) ) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if ( !$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract ) {
            throw new Exception( 'Invalid table data gateway provided' );
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable() {

        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable( 'Model_Authentication_DbTable' );
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    public function getRecordById( $id ) {
     $table = $this->getDbTable();
     // Other code here
    }

}
```

And **DbTable** like this:

```
class Model_Authentication_DbTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name    = 'Authentication';
}
```

When It execute `$table = $this->getDbTable();` in Mapper it gives me following error in firebug console:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Message: No adapter found for Model_Authentication_DbTable
```

How to set adapter for this DbTable ?

Anyone know about this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find the solution. I just comment out some lines in application.ini and everything is working:**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

;[staging : production]

;[testing : production]
;phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
;phpSettings.display_errors = 1

;[development : production]
;phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
;phpSettings.display_errors = 1
;resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "bbname"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Comment: You don't need to comment those lines. Just move the db information to the end of the [production] section. The following sections will inherit the configuration from the preceding ones. Also note that while you are developing, you need to add to your server configuration: SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development, so that you can see the errors (that's what the phpSettings.display_startup_errors, etc. in the development section are for.

Comment: @user570783: you are right. Thanks for your interest in this post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the zf tools? The following command should help you to create a db adapter in your production section for the MySQL database:

```
zf.sh configure db-adapter "adapter=PDO_MYSQL&host=localhost&dbname=test&username=testuser&password=testpasswort&charset=utf8" production
```

Just be sure you have the PDO driver for MySQL installed on your machine.