# Unable to access module forms in module controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-controller, zend-framework-modules

I have a test module. In test module I have a Form in forms folder.

**myproject/application/modules/test/forms/TestForm.php**

```
class Test_Form_TestForm extends Zend_Form {
    //form elements
}
```

**myproject/application/modules/test/controllers/TestController.php**

```
class Test_TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->view->form = new Test_Form_TestForm();  // this is generating error
    }
} // end class
```

Form initialization in controller is generating following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test_Form_TestForm' not found in C:\wamp\www\student\application\modules\notification\controllers\NotificationController.php on line 16
```

How to make this form accessable in controller. Same type of case is working with default controller. I know I have to register my module in bootstrap with Form_ indicator but dont know exact syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also initialize multiple modules in a separate function in one Bootstrap file like:

```
protected function _initAutoloaders() {

        $test_loader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader( array(   'namespace' => 'Test',
                                                                            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/test'
        ));


      $mynew_loader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader( array(    'namespace' => 'Mynew',
                                                                            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/mynew'
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order for `Zend Autoloader` to work for your modules, you need to have bootstraps for all of your modules, and also modules resource initialized.

So, in your `application/modules/test/Bootstrap.php`:

```
class Test_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

**Upd:**

And in your `application/configs/application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"    
resources.modules[] =
```

More info about autoloading in modules [here](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/)

Comment: I have created Test_Bootstrap class in **application/modules/test/Bootstrap.php** But same error. Can you provide some more info.

Answer (score 2):

Vika's answer is correct on how to setup modules autoloader.

Your error states that the form class cannot be found in notification module under NotificationController controller.

So you need to have bootstrap class for the notification module

In your `application/modules/notification/Bootstrap.php:`

```
class Notification_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works.

In your bootstrap

```
...
$autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
$autoloader->addResourceType('Test_Form', '/test/forms', 'Test_Form');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Vika's answer seems to be correct.

If you still having problems, try modify your **application.ini**

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleDefault = "test"
resources.modules[] = "test"
resources.modules[] = "other"
```

If you specify exact module names in resource list, Zend will auto-magically register the Form and other resource auto-loaders. In debugging case **modules/test/Boostrap.php** should be triggered and any _init method inside. Have fun.